# The chromatic polynomial $P(G, k)$ of a graph is always $\geq k!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring

I was playing around with the chromatic polynomial earlier today, when I stumbled upon the following result:

If $G$ has a $k$-coloring, then $P(G, k) \geq k!$

I came up with the following proof, but I can't find this result anywhere online, so my question is, what's wrong with my proof?

**Proof**: If there exists a k-coloring $f: V(G) \to C$, we can induce atleast $k! - 1$ more k-colorings, them being the permutations of $C$. Together with $f$, we have atleast $k!$ k-colorings and so $P(G, k) \geq k!$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: The usual definition of the chromatic polynomial $P(G,k)$ counts all the $k$-colorings of $G$, including those that don't actually use all $k$ colors. So, for example, if $G$ is the complete graph on three points, then $P(G,5)=5\cdot4\cdot3=60$, which is less than $5!=120$.

Comment: So then the whole "permutations of $C$" part would not hold, since $f$ isn't necessarily surjective?